# WebSQL database creating, then deleting itself

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a webSQL database. Been troubleshooting for a long while now, and tried many different things, haven't gotten anywhere. Took it down to one hard coded function.  From watching the developer tools in Chrome, it seems to be creating the database initially, and immediately deleting it.

Anyone have any idea where I'm  going wrong? Very new to Javascript so it could be something small.

Thanks.

```
<script>

    function writeToDatabase(){
    var my_array = new Array();
    my_array[0] = "23 November 2013";
    my_array[1] = "3:00 AM";
    my_array[2] = "Go to the doctor for yearly checkup";
    my_array[3] = "Doctor visit";
    var db = openDatabase('events_db', '1.0', 'DB for storing event details', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVENTS (id integer primary key autoincrement, date, time, description, title)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO EVENTS (date, time, description, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', my_array);
    });
    window.alert("done");
    db.transaction(function (tx) {

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM EVENTS', [], function (tx, results) {
     var len = results.rows.length, i;
     msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";

     for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
       window.alert(results.rows.item(i).description);
      }
    }, null);
    });

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to execute CREATE - INSERT - SELECT operations as callback of each operation (inside db.transaction):

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVENTS (id integer primary key autoincrement, date, time, description, title)', [], function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO EVENTS (date, time, description, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', my_array, function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM EVENTS', [], function (tx, results) {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Although this looks awful, it's the way WebSQL works.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test that yet.. Ended up jumping ship and storing with HTML5 for what we were using. Thanks for your help though!